LFS: coreutils 9.4 build results in a help2man error and fails
I was building a LFS system when I moved on to the coreutils step as described here. After compiling man/nice.1, the "build" fails because help2man fails to gather information from the corresponding "--help" command for man/chroot.td/chroot.
Here is the output:
  CCLD     src/getlimits
  GEN      man/chroot.1
  GEN      man/hostid.1
  GEN      man/timeout.1
  GEN      man/nice.1
help2man: can't get `--help' info from man/chroot.td/chroot
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
make[2]: *** [Makefile:27782: man/chroot.1] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
help2man: can't get `--help' info from man/timeout.td/timeout
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
help2man: can't get `--help' info from man/nice.td/nice
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
make[2]: *** [Makefile:27782: man/timeout.1] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:27782: man/nice.1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/ben/6a03968c-3859-4041-8752-2a48c34214f6/sources/coreutils'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:22396: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/ben/6a03968c-3859-4041-8752-2a48c34214f6/sources/coreutils'
make: *** [Makefile:8835: all] Error 2

The "configure" options:
./configure --prefix=/usr                     \
            --host=$LFS_TGT                   \
            --build=$(build-aux/config.guess) \
            --enable-install-program=hostname \
            --enable-no-install-program=kill,uptime


I have tried running a patch as described on section 8.57.2.
I have tried redownloading coreutils 9.4.
I have tried updating help2man.

I want to either disable help2man altogether since I will not be using the manual, or fix the bug so it no longer occurs. Is there any way I can do this?
